# Is it possible to open from Java, gnome-terminal without bash running in it?

Tags: java, terminal, gnome-terminal

I need a custom REPL for a Java program. The REPL cannot read and write to the terminal window from which java is called, because its output would intermingle with that of a needed library that frequently writes to stdout (and the library's output is important).

So, I'd like to open a second gnome-terminal window, and have it interact with Java in the same way a normal gnome-terminal process interacts with bash: terminal sends user input to JVM (not bash); JVM sends output to terminal which displays it to the user.

However, opening gnome-terminal with `ProcessBuilder` results in a terminal window running bash (the default behavior).  Is it possible to prevent this and get the terminal's output with the `InputStream` returned by `Process.getInputStream()` and send output to it with the `OutputStream` returned by `Process.getOutputStream()`?

Java would need to behave like an "application designed to run on xterm" according to gnome-terminal's man page.  But there's no further explanation on what this means.

Any experiences on doing this?

Comment: No. That is not possible. You can run another program in the gnome-terminal, but you can't capture its' stdin or stdout.

Comment: Guess the only option is implement it in FX.

Comment: @ARX so you want to run a process from java and provide input from the application and get output inside java application? am i right? can you provide a sample code on what you want to achieve and what are you struggling with?